# CSS horizontal alignment of a child DIV

Tags: html, css

I need to make either the child DIV itself right aligned or the SPAN within it right aligned. I expected the following code to work for this. What am I missing? It's still left aligned.

For some reason CSS does not seem to have a "horizontal-align" property (massive oversight?). So I decided to try making the span the full width and right align the text to achieve the same effect.

```html
<div id="something" style="width: 600px">
  <div id="somethingElse">
    <span style="width: 100%; text-align: end;">My Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "end" was auto suggested from Chrome's F12 tools?

Comment: @Paulie_D - Yes it is, although it's considered expermental. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Answer (score 2):

`span` is inline and alignment will not work since it adjusts itself only up to the content width. If you need to retain the span element, then use `text-align: end` for the parent element or else replace it with `div`.

```css
#somethingElse {
  text-align: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="something" style="width: 600px">
  <div id="somethingElse">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CSS float attribute if it is the span tag that you want right-aligned.

```
<span style="float: right;">My Text</span>
```

EDIT:

Use text-align: right; if it is the text inside span you want right-aligned;

Answer (score 0):

`span` elements are inline by default and so collapse to their own width.

Setting the element to `display:block` allows you to set a width.

Then align the text to the right.

```css
#something {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
span {
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="something" style="width: 600px">
  <div id="somethingElse">
    <span style="width: 100%; text-align: end;">My Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take your existing CSS and move it from the span to the div above it:

```html
<div id="something" style="width: 600px">
  <div id="somethingElse" style="width: 100%; text-align: end;">
    <span>My Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```